# Replace common values in two files according to first column

Tags: text-processing, scripting, columns

How do I replace common values in two files according to first column?

I have file 1 (1.txt):

```
CH063_01084
CH063_01083
CH063_13925
CH063_14473
```

and file 2 (2.txt):

```
CH063_01083         FGSG_16349  4
CH063_14473         FGSG_16350  5
```

output file should be :

```
CH063_01084
CH063_01083          FGSG_16349 4
CH063_13925
CH063_14473          FGSG_16350 5
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/join.html) for this:

```
join -a 1 file1 file2
```

`join` combines files based on a common field. By default that is the first field of both files. `-a 1` means to include lines from the first file when there was no pair. To pick fields other than the first, use `-1 N -2 M` to pick field N from `file1` and M from `file2`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `join`:

```
$ join -a 1 file1.txt file2.txt 
A
B asas 4
C
D addd 5
```

If your file is not sorted:

```
join -a 1 <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt)
```

But it makes you lose your format. You can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -anle ' $h{$F[0]} = $_;
    END { print for sort values %h }
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i have a problem when I run 

join -a 1 1.txt 2.txt > output.txt

it is complained like the following:

join: 1.txt:2: is not sorted: CH063_01083 Any help?

Comment: @user73347: Updated my answer!

Comment: The perl option is working great!!! many thanks